# is there any measurable set which is not open,close or Borel?

Tags: abstract-algebra, measurable-functions

is there any measurable set which is not open,close or Borel?
if yes please gimme an example.

Comment: What is your definition of "measurable set" in this context? Without clarity on this your question makes no sense.

Comment: There are more subsets of the Cantor set than there are Borel sets in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: In many ways, this is like asking whether there are any real numbers that are not $0$ or $1$ or algebraic.

Comment: What have you tried, and what do you already know about measurable sets? (And incidentally, "gimme" isn't really that polite.)

Comment: sorry  I am not English, and I didn't know .thank you to mention that.I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I assume Real line $\Bbb R$ with Lebesgue measure.

There exists a subset $S\in \Bbb R$ which is Lebesgue measurable but not a Borel set , since cardinality of set of all Borel set is $\mathscr c$ but cardinality of set of all Lebesgue measurable set is $2^{\mathscr c}$ , where $\mathscr c $ is the cardinality of $\Bbb R$.

If $\phi$ is the cantor function then $\psi :[0,1]\rightarrow [0,2]$ defined by $\psi(x)= x+\phi (x)$ is a homeomorphism. Let $D$ be a non-measurable subset (any measurable subset of positive measure contains a non-measurable subset due to Axiom of Choice) of $\psi (C)$ where $C$ is the cantor set . Then $\psi^{-1} (D)$ is a subset of $C$ and hence is a measurable set of Lebesgue measure $0$ (Lebesgue measure is complete). However since $\psi^{-1} (D)$ is the image under a homeomorphism of a non-Borel set $D$ (as $D$ is not measurable), $\psi^{-1}(D)$ is not a Borel set.

The function $\phi:C\rightarrow \Bbb R$ defined by $\phi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{2^{n+1}}, x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{3^n}$ is a monotone increasing continuous function which is called cantor function.